# dhclient cannot get address from home router

Tags: linux, dhcp

I have a home router providing internet access to my desktop and laptop.
Both computers are running Ubuntu GNU/Linux version 12.04, and have been configured to use DHCP upon installation.
So the router and DHCP are working correctly for these two computers.

I also have an older desktop computer with Ubuntu 10.04. This older desktop is normally not attached to the network, and was not configured to use DHCP.

I have now connected a network cable to it and I wanted to activate a network connection using DHCP. From the command line, I use

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

The result is that the following is printed:

```
Listening on LPF/eth0/...
Sending on   LPF/eth0/...
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.2.106 from 192.168.2.1
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.106 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.106 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.106 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.2.106 from 192.168.2.1
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.106 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.106 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.106 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPNAK from 192.168.2.1
```

I do not know much about DHCP but it seems to me that the router
(192.168.2.1) keeps offering address 192.168.2.106, and then refuses
to acknowledge it. At least, this is what I have understood from [rfc2131](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt).

Do I have to change the configuration of my router, or of my desktop, or both?

**EDIT**

Following the indications of the comments I have added the following block
to the file `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`:

```
interface "eth0"
{
  request subnet-mask;
}
```

but I still have the same errors as above. In particular, I still see

```
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.106 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
```

which means that the `subnet-mask` in my configuration file is ignored.

**EDIT 2**

Problem solved: apparently `dhclient` was not reading the default file `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`. I solved the problem by:

- Calling `dhclient` with the `-cf` option (specifying the configuration file explicitly).
- Specifying the option `require subnet-mask` instead of `request`: in this way I am sure (AFAIU) that the client is using a subnet mask it got from the router.

Thanks a lot for the hints that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Change the Subnet to at least 255.255.255.252.  255x4 tells dhcp there is no room left in your subnet

Comment: @ECarterYoung that's the broadcast address, not the subnet.

Comment: Look for any logs on your router. That is indeed odd, unless there is some other part of the request (other than the IP address) causing it to be rejected. BTW: Wireshark would be a good tool to actually look at the packets.

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` contains the same messages that I have pasted above.

Comment: @ECarterYoung: Do you know how I can specify the subnet mask? I have not found any such option in `man dhclient`.

Comment: @derobert Apologies, that format always confuses me, as that is the definition for the subnet of the zero network.

Comment: I wish I knew this blue eyed Calomel :) but regardless, [her blog entry on dhclient.conf](https://calomel.org/dhclient.html) may point you in the right direction.

Comment: I had already found this page. If I find the solution I will report it here.

Comment: Try using the request directive.

Comment: hi guys sorry for interrupt, I need a help on dhcp server. Could you check this one http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140387/pxeboot-client-not-getting-ip-address-from-the-dhcp-server